Prevent boil off in StarShip fuel depot by a JWST-like sunshield?
Can we use Webb’s telescope shield to prevent or significantly reduce boil off of propellant from StarsShip fuel depot, made from a single StarShip in Earth orbit?
For JWST, its sunshield covers its hexagonal mirror and optics package, but for our case what size shield do we need to have and by what principle would it cool the cryogenic fuels? If anything both Webb’s sunshield and methalox are pink (as shown in image below).

Thanks in advance.

The sun shield was insanely expensive and difficult to make, making it 5 times bigger to cover starship wouldn't make it any cheaper. Probably not worth the effort

The third paragraph about hydrolox/methalox is a separate question. It's probably better to remove this part and just ask the sun-shield question. Maybe asked the hydrolox/methalox question separately.

I agree with Galerita; we can ask as many questions as we like in Stack Exchange, and often the answer to one helps to formulate the basis for the next. And there's even a close reason called "needs focus". The question about how to keep your LOX cold in space until you're ready to e̶a̶t̶ use it is great by itself! And LOX only needs to be kept at ~ 90 K to minimize boiling, whereas the JWST requires a very constant temperature below 50 K. A thermal transient on JWST would shut down observation for a while, whereas would just mean a little less LOX o̶n̶ y̶o̶u̶r̶ p̶l̶a̶t̶e̶ in your tank.

So I don't think we can a priori assume this would by extension be as insanely expensive and insanely difficult as the shield for JWST. That one absolutely had to work and work perfectly, or a truely insane amount of money and time would be lost, whereas there's always more LOX in the sea..

Good point I’ve created separate question for the lox part https://space.stackexchange.com/q/65978/54861

I'd say yes. See https://webb.nasa.gov/content/observatory/sunshield.html to learn more about how the JWST sunshield works.

@uhoh, per you comment since fuel depot would require only half of the cryogenic temperatures of the Webb, its shield could be thinner but wider so in theory the same size and price overall. If you take Webb mirror out of price, you could get it may be for 5b, not a horrible price long term.

@estinamir the insane cost of development was not in the size, but in the reliability, because if it failed US$10 billion and at least another decade would go down the drain. That's where the cost is! This doesn't apply to a tank of smoked salmon (I mean LOX).

The cost of  such a shade would depend on many factors such as the trade off between active cooling v shield size, shape and material used. I suspect that if SpaceX were building it the cost might be very significantly reduced from anything remotely like JWST levels.

"Can we use Webb’s telescope shield to prevent or significantly reduce boil off of propellant from StarsShip fuel depot in Earth orbit?"
Yes we could. However the JWST required very low temperatures in order to ensure its highly sensitive instruments worked properly. It would not be necessary to cool Starship to the same degree so using the JWST shield would be very expensive and unnecessary.
"what size shield do we need to have?"
It really depends on to what extent you want to reduce the boil off and how reflective it is. It would be best to shield the whole vehicle to prevent conduction through the skin from the cargo bay area down to the propellant tanks. It would be most important to shield Starship from the Sun, but shielding from Earth light would also be very beneficial.
"By what principle would it cool the cryogenic fuels?"
The shield would firstly prevent radiation from the Sun and Earth being absorbed by the tanks and warming them up. With sufficient shielding the tanks would lose energy by radiation. In the most extreme case, if Starship was 100% shielded from everything except deep space Starship would slowly cool down to the background temperature of space of just under 3 degrees K.
However this process would take a long time due to the mass of Starship and the fact that the contents of the tanks are liquid. The cooled liquids would slowly freeze but this would also involve removing the latent heat of fusion and radiating that away to. But given sufficient time the contents would freeze completely solid and tend towards around 3 degrees K.

It's not quite true that the JWST sunshade would be overkill for cooling hydrogen. In fact it would come up a bit short. The sunshade cools the shaded side of JWST down to about -233 degrees Celsius (40 Kelvin). Hydrogen boils at a slightly lower temperature of 20 Kelvin ( –253° C) . JWST then uses a two-stage nitrogen and helium cryocooler to bring some of the instruments down to 7 K (-266° C). The first stage of the cooler brings the temp down to 18 K, so really only the second stage of the cryocooler would be overkill.

You are correct. Although I had assumed that the cryogenic propellants would be liquid methane and liquid oxygen since methalox was mentioned and they are being stored in a Starship which has tanks designed for methalox.

Yes fully agree for the Starship question that you were answering the JWST sunshade would be somewhat overkill. But maybe all they have to do is build it with fewer layers for methane, somewhat reducing the complexity. As for a hydrogen fuel depot maybe the shade would just need more layers. Of course it may not be quite that simple.

At the 40K of the JWST shield you just need your tanks to take >15 bar pressure to keep in the supercritical phase.

@Jon Custer sadly they won't take much more than about 8 bar.

@Slarty - perhaps better put that the current conceptual design won't take more than about 8 bar?

@jon Custer yes true. They could increase the wall thickness to allow for extra pressure for a tanker variant. But I'm not sure how much would be needed or what the weight penalty would be.

Well, the weight penalty is on the launch of the tank. The boil-off penalty requires more launches of fuel. Sounds like a nice operations engineering trade study.

Yes it would require a careful consideration of multiple trade offs (above my pay grade). The tank redesign development and weight penalty, additional mass capacity benefit, the size, shape, effectiveness and cost of any shield and the mass and development penalty of a shield or active cooling device...

There is no such thing as degrees K. It's just K on its own

Thanks for that. I have corrected it
